# Css Style isn't matching or refusing to match the element

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an opensource fluid html layout that uses jQuery too. There is one issue that has been driving me nuts as I was unable to solve the problem for the past few hours. I'm sure I'm missing something that is rather simple, if you could help me find it I would appreciate it.

**The problem is** when I try to make the div#content-wrapper have a `min-height` and `margin-left`/`margin-right`. Basically it should fill the page and have some spaces to the left and right.

It looks fine when it is viewed in the work space of cssdeck http://cssdeck.com/labs/fluid-html-template however when you go to view in full screen at http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/fluid-html-template/0, on Chromium Developer Tools (F12) I see that `#content-wrapper` class isn't matched for `div#content-wrapper` style rule under `Matched CSS Rules`. What could be causing this? The only way I found to override this was to apply style directly to the `div` tag with the `style` attribute.

Since the template was written in jade-lang here is the computed html, JavaScript and CSS codes to make things easier.

---

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/WeaponXI/cplog/raw/master/public/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/WeaponXI/cplog/master/public/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>WeaponXI</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top-nav ui-widget-header">Home | Login | Etc</div>
      <div class="header">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="menu ui-widget-header">
          <div id="menu">
            <ul>
              <li> <a href="/" title="Home"> Home</a>
                <ul>
                  <li> <a href="/users" title="Users"> Users</a>
                  </li>
                  <li> <a href="/users2" title="Users"> Users</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li> <a href="/cplog" title="Captains Logs"> Captains Logs</a>
              </li>
              <li> <a href="/contact" title="Contact"> Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="left-panel"></div>
      <div id="content-wrapper" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <div id="content">Content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-panel"></div>
      <div class="bottom-panel"></div>
    </div><!--
    <end>wrapper</end>-->
    <footer>
      <div id="footer"><em>Copyright © 2013 WeaponXI.com</em></div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}
.top-nav {
    z-index:0 !important;
    padding:4px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:white;
    font-size:0.8em;
    opacity:0.6;
}
.top-nav:hover {
    opacity:0.9;
}
.header {
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
.logo {
    /*width: 451px;*/

    height:130px;
    background-image:url(https://github.com/WeaponXI/cplog/raw/master/public/images/logo.png);
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.menu {
    z-index:0 !important;
    position:relative;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
font-size : 0.7em;
}
.ui-menu { position: absolute; width: 100px;}

​
#content-wrapper {
        width:auto;
        margin-left:20px;
                margin-right:20px;
                min-height:600px;
                margin-bottom:20px;
}
#content {
    padding: 20px;
    font:1em;
}
footer {

    width: auto;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border-top: thin solid #999;
    display: block;
}
#footer {
    padding:10px;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

**JavaScript:** (This only handles the menu)

```
$(function() {
    $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'menu-p').appendTo('#menu');
    $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'menu-c').appendTo('#menu');
    $('#menu > ul').children('li').children('a').each(function(i) {

        $(this).attr('id', 'menu-p-' + i).parent().children('ul').attr('id', 'menu-c-' + i).appendTo('#menu-c');
        $(this).appendTo('#menu-p').parent().parent().children('ul').remove();

    });
    var shownmenu;
    $('#menu-p').children('a').each(function() {
        var n = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2];
        var button = $(this);
        if ($('#menu-c-' + n).length) {
            button.button({
                text: true,
                icons: {
                    secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                }
            }).hover(function() {
                $('#menu-c-' + n).show().position({
                    my: "left top",
                    at: "left bottom",
                    of: this
                });
            }, function() {
                $('#menu-c-' + n).hover(function() {
                    $('#menu-c-' + n).show();
                }, function() {
                    $('#menu-c-' + n).hide();
                });
                $('#menu-c-' + n).hide();

            });
            $('#menu-c-' + n).hide().menu();
        }
        else {
            button.button();
        }
    });
    $('#menu-p').buttonset();

});
```

Comment: As I was trying to solve the problem I might have made some minor changes that would seem unusual, i.e. I saw that I changed `.content` to `#content-wrapper` in css and html so I edited the question. If you see any anomalies like that please let me know and I will fix it in the question here.

Comment: For some reason html code had a `content` tag, I have fixed it to be `div#content`. I think it changed when I beautified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the syntax. There was a character that was pasted from either jsfiddle or cssdeck. Which prevented the css rule after that special character from being read. I have copy pasted that character and it is:

U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE (That is Unicode U+hex notation)

I used http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ to find out what that character was.

Answer (score 2):

That most likely happens because of the invalid HTML

```
<body onload="__pauseAnimations();">

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

You reach `body` and then start a new `html` which is invalid. The previous CSS defined is not accessible in this `html` (*which is completely invalid anyway..*)

Comment: I also note that in the docs under "Help & Tips" (unfortunately can't refer to it) it says "In the HTML box, you just need to write the code that belongs to your <body>". "If you want to put something that must go inside <head> then you can simply write full HTML that starts either with a doctype or with <html>."  It looks like their support for Jade may be a little incomplete or the right "magic words" haven't been placed.

Comment: @Gaby, could you explain it more please. I couldn't fully understand what you mean... especially the `<body onload="__pauseAnimations();">` is confusing me. Is that what happens in the cssdeck's full page preview? I know there isn't supposed to be a body tag before html tag...

Comment: @Logan, yes. if you view the source of that page you will see what i mean. it seems that at some point it inserts a full html page making it invalid. the `onload` part does play any part.. it was just part of the html.. the problem is the invalid html structure..

Comment: @JayC I just read that in the help&tips, thanks for that info. However it does the same when I run it on my own pc which computes the html as http://pastebin.com/LKza0cYN still the outcome is the same

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli How about my previous comment though, in that pastebin things look fine as far as html right? I have changed the doctype and html tag as well (I thought there was something wrong with it) When things run locally it still looks the same...

Comment: @Logan, if you look at http://jsfiddle.net/CFFB9/ you will see that it gets applied. (in your pastebin there is no element with `content-wrapper` id. Can you post on a pastebin the full html and css (*matching*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli that is really weird though... I don't understand if its Jade that is messing things up. http://pastebin.com/dK3wQWRg here is the pastebin. On my local copy I was using `.content` for `#content-wrapper`

Comment: Seems like the problem is in the css. For some reason `.ui-menu` was causing it. When I removed it, it reads all the styles. Still a mystery though, how it was causing the style after it to be unread.

Comment: could you view it with a hex editor (*or some editor that shows special chars*) and see if there is some *wrong* character before or after that rule that could be breaking the parsing of the file ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    #content-wrapper {
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }
    content {
    padding: 20px;
    font:1em;
    }
```

if you want it to be fluid use percent values..